# MVVM - Handling backing data

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have been struggling with this for awhile now. Until now, I have been keeping my backing data of my MVVM project in a singleton class, but that has started to cause problems for me. I am looking for a good way to keep my backing data in a centralized, easily accessible location, but I don't want to make it static and I'm having trouble implementing such a system.

For example, I have a class called `GameContainer` that holds `ObservableCollection`s of all created objects. I would like to be able to access these `ObservableCollection`s and the object instances contained within throughout my code and I would like to maintain this kind of structure unless there's a better way to do it. If there is a better way, I'd love to learn about it.

I have a method in an initializtion class that, when the program launches, we'll say it creates 10 instances of each object and adds them to the `ObservableCollection`s in `GameContainer`. So now the ViewModel for my main screen needs access to these objects. Without making `GameContainer` static, how can my ViewModel access the required data?

Is this a situation that calls for IOC? If so, how could I appropriately implement that?

Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated. I've been at a standstill here recently and I'd love to be able to continue progress on my project.

Thanks. I look forward to seeing what you have to say.

Comment: Pass `GameContainer` to the view model via its constructor?

Comment: Can you explain why a singleton class is causing problems for you? Based on your description of the problem it sounds like creating a singleton with a static accessor, as Paul recommended, is the best option.

Comment: The problems stemmed from using LINQ to filter and bind data to the UI via an extension called OLinq. At the moment, that extension doesn't work with anything static and apparently even if it did it would cause a memory leak. I suppose it's time to bite the bullet and use `ICollectionView`s to filter my data unless I can find something better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A singleton would generally have a static accessor.

All you need is to have your viewmodels either set a property equal to the GameContainer, or individual properties to the individual memebers of the GameContainer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's what I've been doing. As I mentioned in the comment above, the only reason this wasn't working for me was due to an extension that doesn't behave well with anything static. It may be time to ditch that extension, it seems.